# How to select the exact matches for a list of variables to append datasets

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I have different datasets for different waves. Each wave has its own prefix for both dataset and variables names. I'm trying to import and append all the data files using a subset of variables I need. Therefore, I'm currently doing:

```
 var_list <- c("pidp", "jbsat", "jbhrs", "jbnssec8_dv", "panssec8_dv", "manssec8_dv", "paedqf", "maedqf", "qfhigh", "age_dv",
          "sex_dv", "psu", "strata", "employ", "jbhas", "jboff", "jbsem", "jbstat", "jbterm1", "jbterm2", "pjbptft", "fimnet_dv",
          "fimngrs_dv", "fimnlabnet_dv", "seearnnet_dv", "fimnmisc_dv", "fimnprben_dv", "fimninvent_dv", "fimnpen_dv", "fimnsben_dv", 
          "hhtype_dv", "livesp_dv", "nch14resp", "nmpsp_dv", "tenure_dv", "urban_dv", "jbsat", "health", "sf1", "scghqa",
          "scghqb", "scghqc", "scghqd", "scgqhe", "scgqhf", "scghqg", "scghqi", "scghqj", "scghqh", "scghql", "sclsat1", 
          "sclsat2", "sclsat3", "sclsat4", "indscus_lw", "indscub_xw")
```

Then import the data for the first wave, selecting these variables and remove the wave-prefix:

```
 longfile <- read_dta(file=paste0(dir, "ukhls_w1/a_indresp.dta")) %>% 
 select(matches(var_list)) %>% 
 rename_at(vars(starts_with("a_")), ~str_replace(.,"a_", "")) %>% #remove the wave prefix
 mutate(wave = 1)
```

At this point, I would simply use the following loop:

```
for (wn in 2:10) {
wl <- paste0(letters[wn],"_") 
wave_data <- read_dta(paste0(dir, "ukhls_w", wn, "/", wl, "indresp.dta")) %>% 
select(matches(var_list)) %>% 
rename_at(vars(starts_with(wl)), ~str_replace(.,wl, "")) %>% # remove prefix wave 
mutate(wave = wn)
longfile <- rbind(longfile, wave_data)
}
```

However, the problem is that some variable names matches more than one column in the files for the subsequent waves. For example, in the second wave it exists a variable named "nxtjbhrs", therefore this will be included as it matches "jbhrs". This will create an error in the rbind as the number of columns will differ.

How can I select the exact matches in this case? Or force the appending of the dataset?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select(setdiff(names(.), var_list))
```